# How can I add an author-box below a post?

Tags: widgets, author

I would like to have a box below each blogpost with information about the author.

These screenshots are examples for what I would like to have:
[image]

---

[image]

---

**Links that could help**:

I've found these links so far:

- [Author Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates)

  - [wp_list_authors](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_authors)

I would prefer a plugin (or widget, I don't know the difference), but if nothing like that existed, I would have to adjust **single.php** to my needs, wouldn't I? What would happen, if the theme ([Modern Style](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/modern-style)) got updated?

**Related question**:

[How to add author details in the post sidebar?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47418/7289)

This is not the same question, as I would like to get the box below the post.

But if this is not easily possible: Where should I save the given code?

Comment: This may be what your looking for http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-about-author/

Comment: have you had a look into the code of Twenty Eleven, content-single.php?

Comment: This plugin will be perfect for what you are looking for : https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-author-box-lite/ and http://www.wp-authorbox.com/ Cheers!