# Extra filed under "About the user" user profile

Tags: custom-field, users

I use the following to add Phone number,linked id etc Under the "Contact Info" in user profile. Now I have to add a filed under the "About the user". How can i do that?

```
function my_new_contactmethods( $contactmethods ) {
$contactmethods['designation'] = 'Designation';
$contactmethods['linked_in'] = 'Linked In';
$contactmethods['phone'] = 'Phone Number';
return $contactmethods;
}
add_filter('user_contactmethods','my_new_contactmethods',10,1);
```

**UPDATE**

The above code adds 3 fields to under the section "Contact Info " in the user profile
I don't want to create a new heading called "About the user" and give the required fields. A section with "About the user " is already there in the profile which includes biographical info and password changing option. I want to add a new field there along with those two

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43742/73)?

Comment: Sorry but i didnt see any relationship between my question and that question

Comment: The answer adds an extra field to the user page that can do much more than the `user_contactmethods`. There is no hook immediately below the About section.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in theme's functions.php file.

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
 <table class="form-table">
<tr>
<th><label for="address"><?php _e("Designation"); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="designation" id="designation" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'designation', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><label for="city"><?php _e("Linked In"); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="linked_in" id="linked_in" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'linked_in', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th><label for="province"><?php _e("Phone Number"); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'designation', $_POST['designation'] );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'linked_in', $_POST['linked_in'] );
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone'] );
}
```

Comment: The code I have given in the question works for me. It adds a field under the "Contact Info". I need to add the same under "About The user" in the user profile.

Comment: @MidhuN 'user_contactmethods' filter is used for Customize the contact information fields available to your WordPress users.IF you want separate section for 'about user' then replace you code with the above one.

Comment: I don't want to create a new heading called "About the user" and give the required fields. A section with "About the user " is already there in the profile which includes biographical info and password changing option. I want to add a new field there along with those two

Comment: @MidhuN now i updated above code.Please see.I just removed '<h3>' title from the code.

Comment: @MidhuN if it works then let me know

Comment: No. It didnt work. Please ensure U have understood my question...

Comment: @MidhuN It's working for me.Please replace your code with the above one.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted out using the codes above with combination of another code moving phone field. I would like to share these codes with anyone who need them:

```
/* ADD EXTRA PHONE FIELD INTO USER PROFILE  - WORKING */
// Add a phone field into user profile page
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'extra_user_profile_fields' );
function extra_user_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>
 <table class="form-table">
<tr id="custom_user_field_row">
<th><label for="Phone"><?php _e("Phone Number"); ?></label></th>
<td>
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" value="<?php echo esc_attr( 
get_the_author_meta( 'phone', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }     // Saving Phone field
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_extra_user_profile_fields' );
function save_extra_user_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) ) { return false; }
update_user_meta( $user_id, 'designation', $_POST['designation'] );

update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone', $_POST['phone'] );
}
function moving_extra_field() { // Moving Phone field above Password on user 
profile page
$screen = get_current_screen();
if ( $screen->id != "profile" && $screen->id != "user-edit" ) 
    return;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        field = $('#custom_user_field_row').remove();
        field.insertBefore('#password');
    });
</script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'moving_extra_field' );
```

The above codes will display phone field on user profile page, save it and move it above password. Its not my codes; I combined codes on this site.

Enjoy it!