# WP_editor problem

Tags: wp-editor, bug

A few days ago I asked [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96692/adding-rich-text-editor-to-my-plugin/96713?noredirect=1#96713).

Today I started building a new website in which I copied the code of my plugin used at the website from my previous question.

And I was surprised when I saw that the exact same code that was bugging at my previous website is working perfectly fine in the new website I'm building.

For the people who did not read my previous topic:
At my another website WP_editor is opening in the 'Plain text' field. I can type there and use options like Bold, Italic etc. As soon I switch to the Visual tab, my text is deleted just as all the options. 
All I see is a blanco tab which cannot be edited.

The code I'm using to display the editor:

```
 add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'content' );
                wp_editor(
                    "Sample",
                    'content',
                    array( 'textarea_name' => 'content' )
                );
```

Is someone familiar with this problem or someone who knows a solutions for this?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Getting the following errors:

> GET
>   http://www.domain.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/nl.js?ver=358-23224
>   404 (Not Found) wp-tinymce.php:1
>
> Failed to load:
>   http://www.domain.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/nl.js
>   wp-tinymce.php:1
>
> GET
>   http://www.domain.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/langs/nl.js?ver=358-23224
>   404 (Not Found) wp-tinymce.php:1
>
> Failed to load:
>   http://www.domain.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/themes/advanced/langs/nl.js

Comment: I'm not sure it's safe to call your custom field 'content'. Try renaming it.

Comment: I've done it naming the field content, but it was the only editor on the page.

Comment: I've read the first question and added the proper way to use the wp_editor in a plugin page

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're calling [`add_action()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) correctly.  It should be more like:

```
add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'wpse96952_editor' );
function wpse96952_editor() {
    wp_editor(
        "Sample",
        'mycontent',
        array( 'textarea_name' => 'mycontent' )
    );
}
```

(`content` changed to `mycontent` after I read @vancoder's comment)

Comment: I've added some new errors I currently get

Comment: Do you still have the problems if you disable your plugins and switch to a WordPress default theme like Twenty Twelve?